# Generators of the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

I am a bit confused about the role of propositional variables in the construction of the free Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra.

In the entry "Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra" on Wikipedia, in the section "operations", one can read:

"If the theory is propositional and its set of logical connectives is functionally complete, the Lindenbaum–Tarski algebra is the free Boolean algebra generated by the set of propositional variables."

In the entry "Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra" on PlanetMaths, one can read:

"It can be shown that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of the propositional language 
L is a free Boolean algebra freely generated by the set of all elements $[p]$, where each $p$ is a propositional variable of L."

Which one is correct? Or, perhaps, are these statement both correct? Why?

Comment: If we look at the Lindenbaum algebra as a collection of equivalence classes, the propositional variables aren't literally points of the algebra. So it is natural to read "generated by the propositional variables" as "generated by the equivalence classes of the propositional variables". The more important issue is that, if the theory has non-logical axioms, the algebra may not be a free algebra, as the answer points out.  (If we want to be even more nitpicking, we could say we want the equivalence classes of *formulas that consist of only a propositional variable*.)

Answer (score 4):

The formulation in PlanetMath is attempting to guard against the possibility of non-logical axioms (i.e., non-trivial logical relationships amongst the propositional variables). Both statements are correct if the propositional theories don't have any non-logical axioms. However, for example, if you had an axiom saying that $p \Leftrightarrow q$, for every pair of propositional variables $p$ and $q$, then the equivalence classes $[p]$ would all be equal and the PlanetMath statement would be true, but (assuming you have more than one variable) the Wikipedia statement would be false.

However, the PlanetMath statement is not true in general: there are systems of non-logical axioms that result in Lindenbaum-Tarski algebras that are not free. (Thanks to Alex Kruckman for pointing this out.)

Comment: +1. Considering the generality of the Wikipedia article (which works in the generality of a "logical theory $T$", not specifying whether it may contain non-tautologies) I think the Wikipedia statement is misleading at best. Maybe someone should edit...

Comment: @AlexKruckman: I have edited the Wikipedia article (although my past experience with editing Wikipedia leads me to believe that I will now be pilloried by self-appointed guardians of Wikipedia, who apparently know no mathematics, for changing something in a way that is obviously right without citing an original source $\ddot{\frown}$).

Comment: I think your edit didn't go far enough - the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra may not be free at all, for example if $T$ contains $p\rightarrow q$. I've made a further edit. We'll see how it goes...

Comment: @AlexKruckman. So that everybody (including me) fully understands: Why is the LT algebra not free if e.g. $T$ contains $p\rightarrow q$?

Comment: @student Let's say our set of propositional variables is just $V = \{p,q\}$. Let $B$ be the LT algebra determined by $T$. If $T$ contains $p\rightarrow q$, then we have $p \leq q$ in $B$, but $p$ and $q$ are incomparable in the free Boolean algebra on $V$.

Comment: It's also true that if $T = \{p\rightarrow q\}$ (plus the propositional tautologies, if you don't include them by default), then $B$ is not free on *any* set of generators. Indeed, you can work out that $B$ is a finite boolean algebra with three atoms, $\{p, \lnot p \land q, \lnot p \land \lnot q\}$ ($p \land q = p$, and $p\land \lnot q = 0$, since $p\leq q$), so it has cardinality $2^3 = 8$. But any finite free Boolean algebra has cardinality $2^{2^n}$, where $n$ is the number of generators.

Comment: @AlexKruckman. Thank you for the clarification.